# Nebular Auth: Backend Auth Endpoints <domain> with subpath: Where to setup?

Tags: angular, authentication, nebular

i am using an nebular frontend and a laravel backend.

I am using a subpath like "https://domain/subpath/", which i refer to in the index.html  `<base href="/subpath/">`

Now i got the problem that the nebular auth backend api is not taking the base href. It tries to load
"https://domain/api/v1/auth/login" instead "https://domain/subpath/api/v1/auth/login"

I cant find the option to set the subpath for the auth api.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve it by using an HttpInterceptor for the api route.